# How to feed the actual value on the command where a text file is expected

Tags: unix, command

In my Linux environment, I am using a installed command that is of this format.

```
command1 -u <username> -p <password-file> ...
```

where in this password-file, it keeps a password value of the text format, such as "abc".

When running this command, I feel it is very inconvenient to every time create a file to hold this password value! So is there a way I can feed this "abc" value directly on this command line ???

Thanks, 
Chun

Comment: Update. The command is of this format. "command1 -u username -p password-file ... "

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash (and if you are running in Linux, chances are good you are, or can) you can do:

```
command -u username -p <(echo abc)
```

which is equivalent to passing the name of a file with contents "abc\n".